# Freshly generated DuskTestCase.php throws "Undefined type 'Tests\CreatesApplication'"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to set up Laravel Dusk to test my Laravel site as part of a larger Github Action CI/CD workflow.

Following [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/dusk), I ran:

```
composer require --dev laravel/dusk
php artisan dusk:install
```

The latter command created a `tests/Browser` directory and a `tests/DuskTestCase.php` file.

The problem is that when I open up `DuskTestCase.php` Intelephense immediately complains:

```
Undefined type 'Tests\CreatesApplication'
```

I also get a slightly different, but clearly related, error when running the GitHub Action:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Trait "Tests\CreatesApplication" not found in /home/runner/work/mysite/mysite/tests/DuskTestCase.php on line 10
```

I have the following in my `composer.json`:

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
}
```

...and have also run `composer dump-autoload` locally.

**What's going on here? Why does the example test file generated by Dusk seem to ship with an error and what can I do to fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you deleted the `CreatesApplication` from your app? It comes out of the box with a fresh Laravel installation: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/tests/CreatesApplication.php

Alternatively perhaps you upgraded from an earlier version of Laravel and missed the addition of this file.

Comment: This was the issue. Very weird because I installed a fresh installation of Laravel 8 so there's no reason it shouldn't have existed. Maybe I accidentally deleted the file in my IDE or something.